# Migrating from Google Sign-In for Android to Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Currently, we plan to use [Google Sign-In for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth), as our server authentication method.

This is what we plan to do.

### Client side (Google Sign-In for Android)

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
// This idToken will sent to backend server.
String idToken = account.getIdToken();
```

### Server side (Google Sign-In for Android)

```
// Based on received idToken from client, backend server will call https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=... 
// to identify who is this user.

{
 // These six fields are included in all Google ID Tokens.
 "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
 "sub": "110169484474386276334",
 "azp": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "aud": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "iat": "1433978353",
 "exp": "1433981953",

 // These seven fields are only included when the user has granted the "profile" and
 // "email" OAuth scopes to the application.
 "email": "testuser@gmail.com",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "name" : "Test User",
 "picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kYgzyAWpZzJ/ABCDEFGHI/AAAJKLMNOP/tIXL9Ir44LE/s99-c/photo.jpg",
 "given_name": "Test",
 "family_name": "User",
 "locale": "en"
}
```

---

In the future, we might want to migrate to provide more login option. This is my future migration plan, to migrate from Google Sign-In for Android to Firebase Authentication.

### Client side (Firebase Authentication)

```
FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
mUser.getIdToken(true)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // This idToken will sent to backend server.
                String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();

            } else {
                // Handle error -> task.getException();
            }
        }
    });
```

### Server side (Google Sign-In for Android)

```
# idToken comes from the client app (shown above)
decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(idToken)
uid = decoded_token['uid']
```

---

My questions are

1. For **Google Sign-In for Android**, We plan to store `"sub": "110169484474386276334"`, as an unique identifier to represent a user. Is that a correct field to be used? Is it unique per user? My testing so far is, at client side, we might get different `idToken` for a same user (At different day). Different `idToken` from same user, will **still** yield same `sub` at server side.
2. One day, we might migrate to **Firebase Authentication** to support more login methods. Is it still backward compatible with `Google Sign-In for Android`. Is `Firebase Authentication` able to return same `"sub"` as what is previously returned by `Google Sign-In for Android`? As you can see in the code example, `Firebase Authentication` is returning `uid`.

How can I compare new `Firebase Authentication`'s `uid`, with previous stored `Google Sign-In`'s `sub`?

Comment: Are you planning to use Google sign-in with Firebase Auth? or are you dropping Google sign-in in favor of a different provider? If the former, you can just use `signInWithCredential` with a Firebase Auth wrapped Google credential.

Comment: @bojeil What I plan to do is start adopting "Google Sign-In for Android" (without Firebase Authentication). Later on in the future, I might want to replace it with "Firebase Authentication, to support Google Sign-In, Facebook Sign-In, ...". For former, I plan to store `sub` field. For later, my worry is that I'm not sure "Firebase Authentication" is able to return previous equivalent `sub` field, so that my backend code may perform comparison?

Comment: Actually, Firebase Auth will return the google `sub` field in the Firebase User `providerData` list. There will be a `UserInfo` entry with `uid` equal to that `sub`. You can try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1**: is basically answered [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people):

> A Google account's email address can change, so don't use it to identify a user. Instead, use the account's ID, which you can get on the client with `GoogleSignInAccount.getId()`, and **on the backend** from the `sub` claim of the ID token.

**Q2**: Google as Auth provider for Firebase still uses the same Google sign-in flow (in the beginning), while it then authenticates the user against a Firebase project, as well.

there's an [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) which shows it:

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, REQUESTCODE_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == REQUESTCODE_SIGN_IN) {

        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {

            // Google Sign In was successful
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            String idToken = account.getIdToken();
            // Send token to your backend via HTTPS

            // authenticate with Firebase
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);

        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

where `GoogleSignInAccount account` is still the same response.

**edit**: one can even [verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) from `FirebaseAuth` alike this:

```
FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

mUser.getIdToken(true).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

            String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
            // Send token to your backend via HTTPS

        } else {
            // Handle error -> task.getException();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: For Q2, that is not what I'm asking. What I'm asking is, my legacy server DB is strong `sub` from Google Sign-In. After we migrate to Firebase Authentication, Firebase Authentication is returning `uid`. How can I compare new Firebase Authentication's uid, with previous stored Google Sign-In's sub?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng unless the accounts where previously linked, that might not be possible. using Firebase Auth from the beginning might be useful, in order to build up the user database there already, despite not yet using it... because else one can only hope nobody has changed his email address associated with the Google account. maybe one cloud function (firebase-admin) would be required, in order to delete users which were deleted from the other database, in order to keep these in-sync.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng found out how to get the ID token from `FirebaseAuth` (which should at least be the same while Google Sign-In was used as auth-provider), which also has field `sub`. updated my answer. building up both user databases at the same time still might make sense, because then one has had everybody logged in once already - with the matching `sub`.